# CLLocationManager.location is nil in 10.10, but works in 10.11

Tags: swift, macos, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my [DC Metro tracking application](https://github.com/clrung/DCMetroWidget), I use `CoreLocation` to select the Metro station nearest the user and also present a list of stations near them.

It works perfectly in macOS 10.11, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on macOS 10.10.  To debug this, I inserted a line in the `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` method in `TodayViewController.swift` to print the location fetched by the application.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    LocationManager.sharedManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(LocationManager.sharedManager.location)

    ...
}
```

On El Capitan, this outputs the following to the console (success):

```
Optional(<+38.92208178,-77.22920176> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/18/16, 5:04:37 PM Eastern Daylight Time)
```

On Yosemite, it just outputs `nil`.

I have also tried to simulate my location to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Location services are enabled on the Yosemite machine, and I know that it is working because the Weather Notification Center widget is correctly fetching its location.

Thank you!

More relevant code:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    ...

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .Authorized:
        if !didSelectStation {
            selectedStationLabel.stringValue = "Determining closest station..."
        }
        LocationManager.sharedManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .NotDetermined:
        getCurrentLocationButton.hidden = false
        mainPredictionView.hidden = true
    default:    // Denied or Restricted
        WMATAfetcher.getPredictionsForSelectedStation()
    }
}

class LocationManager {
    static let sharedManager: CLLocationManager = {

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0

        return locationManager
    }()
}
```

I also have a button, `getCurrentLocationButton`, that calls `startUpdatingLocation()`

```
@IBAction func getCurrentLocation(sender: NSButton) {
    LocationManager.sharedManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing before calling `stopUpdatingLocation()`? Also, have you implemented the [`locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:) delegate method?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I did implement the `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)` delegate method. I thought that since my call to `print()` in `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` executed I wouldn't have to worry about it.As a sanity check, I added a `print()` statement to that method and it did not execute at runtime.  Thank you, @Deyton!

Comment: Your original suggestion fixed it!  When I moved the `LocationManager.sharedManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` call to after `print(LocationManager.sharedManager.location)`, it successfully displayed the current location.  Thanks again, @Deyton!

Comment: Great! I'll move that suggestion to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accessing `location` before calling `stopUpdatingLocation()`?